# Snort+Barnyard with Graylog

Tags: security, logging, snort, graylog

I have installed Snort and Barnyard2 following [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/122/original/Snort_2.9.9.x_on_Ubuntu_14-16.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA&Expires=1515432063&Signature=PboH6CsDl6453z0Skxbsy%2FqyU4o%3D) guide.
I was about to install BASE but it requires PHP5 and it's no longer supported. I have PHP7 installed and cannot downgrade it.

After a bit of lurking I decided to use Graylog2 to view the logs.

Snort is configured to log in unified2 format then barnyard2 reads that and saves it to MySQL database.
As far as I understood (not much) logging to MySQL is pointless without BASE and I need to forward the logs to Graylog.

Now, should I

1) Remove Barnyard and tell Snort to log in human-readable format (not very efficient?) then send the logs to Graylog

2a) Tell Barnyard to stop sending the logs to MySQL but forward them directly to Greylog

2b) Tell Barnyard to just translate unified2 and write the human-readable log to another file then send it to Graylog.

In any case, How?

Snort, Barnyard and Graylog are on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've come up with this but I would like an opinion from someone who knows more than me.

Remove this from barnyard2 config file ([example](https://pastebin.com/PYmqyUQ9) - Line 258 to 296)

`output database: log, mysql, user=snort password=************** dbname=snort host=localhost sensor_name=sensor01`

and add the proper output for syslog

`output alert_syslog`

(OR `output log_syslog_full: sensor_name whatever, server 127.0.0.1, protocol udp, port 514` ?)

Then in syslog config (graylog documentation, [here](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/sending_data.html#syslog))

`*.* @graylog.example.org:514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format`

Comment: It should work but it really seems like a silly relay race. There has to be a cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure barnyard to log directly to your Graylog server. Instead of logging via syslog to localhost, you just create a new syslog input on your Graylog server and point the barnyard syslog output to that ip/port.